# Python: Read POST Parameters

Tags: python, post, http-post

I've never used python before but need to write a fairly simple script for a project I'm working on. All I need is a script that listens on port 80 for incoming HTTP POSTs and prints the posted variables/parameters and values to the command line. 
What's the easiest way for a beginner to get this done?

Thanks.

Comment: Almost certainly Flask. http://flask.pocoo.org

Comment: If you're allowed to use 3rd party libraries..  Bottle.py should do the trick.

Comment: @pvg thanks for your response. do you know of any sample code that does that?

Answer (score 3):

Consider using Flask Framework. With just 7-8 lines your job is done.
It will print all parameter sent using post and get request to your console.
Also I would recommend to learn it.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/",methods=['POST','GET'])
def index():
    print request.form
    return "Please Check your command line"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=80,debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at it. Yes I'm planning on learning it. I normally don't post questions like that on SO. Thanks for helping me anyway!

Comment: Hi, I got that script to run. Now I want to pass the POST values to a third party python lib (uses TCP internally). Calling that lib works well outside the index() function. But within it I don't receive anything in my 3rd party lib. Any ideas why that is? Thanks

Comment: You could pass the request.form to that function like below

@app.route("/",methods=['POST','GET'])
def index():
    print request.form
    myThirdPartyFunction( request.form )
    return "Please Check your command line"
def myThirdPartyFunction(data):
     # do something with data